# Trapezoidal pyramid

Tags: geometry

Is the following problem correct? If it is correct, please present a solution.

Given a trapezoidal pyramid ABCDM. The base $ABCD$ is trapezoid (where $AB\;  ||\; CD$). The planes $ADM$ and $BCM$ are perpendicular to the base $ABCD$. If $AB=5$, $DC=3$, $S_{\triangle BCM}=9$ and $S_{\triangle ABM}=20$, find the volume of the pyramid.

[image]

Comment: I think that it is, but I cannot solve it.

Comment: The area of a pyramid is $\frac{1}{3}A_{base}h$.  Where $A_{base}$ is the area of the base (no matter the shape) and $h$ is the height.

Comment: Correction to my comment: The *volume* of a pyramid...

Comment: "The planes ADM and BCM are perpendicular to the base ABCD"  This is physically impossible.

Comment: @Tpofofn: No, it isn't.

Comment: @jorki, Yes, I see it now, M is on the line where ADM and BCM intersect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data given does not determine the volume of the pyramid.

Note that since $ADM$ and $BCM$ are perpendicular to $ABCD$, it follows that $M$ lies above the intersection $P$ of $AD$ and $BC$. Let $h$ be the height of $M$ above $P$, let $x$ be the perpendicular distance from $P$ to $AB$, and let $d$ be the perpendicular distance between $CD$ and $AB$. Then

$$S_{\triangle BCM}=\frac12 h|BC|=9$$

and

$$S_{\triangle ABM}=\frac12\sqrt{x^2+h^2}|AB|=20\;,$$

and with $|AB|=5$ this yields

$$x^2+h^2=64\;.$$

We also have

$$\frac{x-d}x=\frac35\;,$$

so $x=\frac52d$, and thus

$$\left(\frac52d\right)^2+h^2=64\;.$$

Writing $d=|BC|\cos\alpha$, with $\alpha$ the angle between $BC$ and the perpendicular on $AB$ and $CD$, we arrive at

$$\left(\frac52|BC|\cos\alpha\right)^2+\left(\frac{18}{|BC|}\right)^2=64\;.$$

Solving for $\cos\alpha$ yields

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{64-(18/|BC|)^2}}{\frac52|BC|}\;.$$

Setting this to zero yields $|BC|\gt\frac94$, and the value is below $1$ in that entire range with a maximum of $32/45$ at $|BC|=\frac94\sqrt2$.

With $V=\frac13hd(|AB|+|CD|)/2=\frac43hd=\frac43h|BC|\cos\alpha=24\cos\alpha$, the volume of the pyramid can take any value between $0$ and $256/15\approx17$.

Comment: Thanks. How do you obtain the upper limit for the volume? Could you explain it in details, please?